# Force passing a type parameter

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion, type-parameter

For some reason I have

```
val stuff: Map[String, Any] = Map[String, Any](
  ("a", 1),
  ("b", "one"),
  ("c", false)
)

def getThing[T](key: String): T = {
  stuff.get(key).get.asInstanceOf[T]
}

val a: Int = getThing("a") // I want this to break on compile
val anotherA: Int = getThing[Int]("a") // I want this to work as normal
```

I want the get's **without** specifying the type to break on compile, and the ones that **do** specify to work.

Comment: Don't think it's possible.

Comment: You can't stop `T` from being inferred to be `Int`, so it's basically both the exact same thing...

Comment: "For some reason". Why?

Comment: @Paul A large + complex existing system is making problems from inferred types. This solution would have been quicker and a bit cleaner, but it sounds like i'll be digging deeper to find another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't force a type argument to be provided explicitly.
Maybe you can turn it into a normal argument, if you really want this behaviour...

```
case class Type[T]

def getThing[T](t: Type[T])(key: String): T =
  stuff.get(key).get.asInstanceOf[T]

val a = getThing(Type[Int])("a")
```